# SQL doesn't allow me to insert data

Tags: sql, mysqli

creating table and inserting data into a table and now it giving me an error

> SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (S21403051.SYS_C007300)
>   violated - parent key not found         02291. 00000 - "integrity
>   constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"         *Cause:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
 CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
 FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR(10),
 SURNAME VARCHAR(15),
 CUSTOMER_TEL VARCHAR(12),
CUSTOMER_EMAIL VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_1', 'CUST_102', 'EMP_51');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_3','CUST_101','EMP_51');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_3','CUST_101','EMP_53');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_5','CUST_103','EMP_54');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_5','CUST_107','EMP_54');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_1', 'CUST_106','EMP_55');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_1','CUST_108','EMP_55');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_5','CUST_104','EMP_51');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_3','CUST_109','EMP_51');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_2','CUST_1010','EMP_52');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_2','CUST_1010','EMP_55');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_5','CUST_101','EMP_51');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES VALUES ( 'CRUISE_5','CUST_103','EMP_51');
```

Comment: Can we see the code for the customer_cruises table creation?

Comment: Can you post the table structure of CUSTOMER_CRUISES

Comment: WHY ARE YOU YELLING AT US!!!

Comment: SORRY I DIDINT MEA TOO

Answer (score 2):

When you have defined 6 columns CUSTOMER_ID , FIRST_NAME  , SURNAME ,
 CUSTOMER_TEL,CUSTOMER_EMAIL and when you try to insert values, it takes in order of table definition. Instead you can try this way 
Example:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CRUISES 
(column1, clumn2,column3)
 values ('xx','xy','yz')
```

Yet, you can not insert duplicate value into first column as primary key is defined on it. And, it cant be null.
Hope this helps

Comment: CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_CRUISES(
 CRUISE_ID VARCHAR(10),
 CUSTOMER_ID  VARCHAR(10),
 EMPLOYEE_ID  VARCHAR(10),
 FOREIGN KEY (CRUISE_ID) REFERENCES CRUISE(CRUISE_ID),
 FOREIGN  KEY ( CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER( CUSTOMER_ID), 
 FOREIGN  KEY ( EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE( EMPLOYEE_ID) 
); WAS REFERING O THIS TABLE

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**: **A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.**

This problem arises when you attempt to insert a record containing the Customer_ID column into the child table (CUSTOMER_CRUISES) and that this Customer_ID is not present in the parent table (CUSTOMER). When the Customer_ID (Foreign key) in CUSTOMER_CRUISES table does not get to reference the Customer_ID (primary key) in CUSTOMER table, an error is raised.

One workaround is to insert and make sure that the value is present in the CUSTOMER table first before inserting the values into the CUSTOMER_CRUISES table.